# Django design patterns for radio buttons with additional fields

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm not sure what these kinds of fields are technically called, but they're the ones where you have a group of radio selects, and each one can some additional fields that only get validated if its associated radio is selected.

```
Field Label:
(*) Option 1
( ) Option 2 [Additional Field]
( ) Option 3 [Another Field], [Maybe Two]
```

The key things I'm looking for:

1) Any existing solution for aiding in the rendering of such fields. ie grouping the additional fields with their options.
2) (not as important) any shortcuts for handling the validation, ie only bother validating the additional fields if their option is selected.

Normally when I do this kind of thing I end up having to manually write a lot of the HTML which is a wheel I'd rather avoid having to keep re-inventing.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you can use some js, for example (with jQuery):

```
$('input[name=your_radio_field_name]').change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'option1_value':
            $('input[name=extra_field_for_option2], input[name=extra_field_for_option3]').hide();
            break;
        case 'option2_value':
            $('input[name=extra_field_for_option2]').show();
            $('input[name=extra_field_for_option3]').hide();
            break;
        // and so on ...
    } 
})
```

On server side, you could have such field validation functions:

```
def clean_extra_field_for_option2(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('your_radio_field_name') != 'option_2_value':
        return None
    return self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field_for_option2')

def clean_extra_field_for_option3(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('your_radio_field_name') != 'option_3_value':
        return None
    return self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field_for_option3')
```

Of course, if you have this case a lot, you should first try something simple like this, and then refactor.

Comment: I'm not really looking to show/hide the additional fields depending on which radio is selected. In the simplest case I'd always want all the fields to be visible. What I'm trying to figure out is if there are any existing solutions/patterns for integrating other fields into the renderer for the RadioSelect widget.

Comment: "Any existing solution for aiding in the rendering of such fields. ie grouping the additional fields with their options" [form and template rendering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template) "only bother validating the additional fields if their option is selected" see python example, "a group of radio selects, and each one can some additional fields" see js example.